# Django 1.4: How to get only the true string from Bla.objects.filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```

Now i need a output like this (so i can use it like djangos `{{ form.as_p }}`):

```
<div id="question-1">The string in question"</div>
<div id="question-2">The string in another question"</div>
...
```

With `loq = Questions.objects.filter(created_by=user)` i get `[<Questions: My first question!>,...]` in `str(loq)`.

Is there an easier way than to search `str(loq)` with `.find()`?

EDIT:

Solved it this way (thanks to [Samuele Mattiuzzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754484/samuele-mattiuzzo)):

models.py:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```

views.py:

```
def ViewQuestions(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        loq = Questions.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)

        return render(request, "main/questions.html", {'loq': loq})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

questions.html:

```
{% for q in loq %}
<div id="question-{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ q.question }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a template file (say questions.html) like this:

```
{% for q in loq %}
    <div id="question-{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ q.question }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

in your views.py, you have to return your queryset (which is your loq)

```
def view_questions(response, user):
    loq = Questions.objects.filter(created_by=user)
    return render_to_response(
        'questions.html',
        locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

locals() is the dictionary containing your loq. here i'm assuming you already know how django works. i don't really get what you mean with that ".find()" statement, tho.

you may also want to change the created_by field from CharField to ForeignKey poiting to the User class

check the docs about [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) and [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/) for more knowledge on the subject.

if this doesn't answer, provide some more explanation and i'll be updating the answer